# How can I get the Windows 7 USB driver working for my Android Tablet?

Tags: tablet, usb-connection-mode

I have a Tech_7 from Chinavasion, S3C6410 Android 1.6;

When I plug it into the usb port, it shows up in the Device manager as HiDROID, but the driver is not installed.

How can I get the USB driver working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install the avd & sdk manager - I'm assuming you use c:\Android_SDK
- Edit c:\Android_SDK\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
  Find the section [Google.NTx86] and add the following:

`;Techpad

%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0002

%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0002&MI_01`

Find the section [Google.NTamd64] and add the following:

```
;Techpad  
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0002  
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0002&MI_01
```

- Edit .android\adb_usb.ini and add the following:

`0x18D1`

**Note:  This corresponds to the device id up top**

- Plug device in - you should have an unknown device in the device manager.
- Update the driver on it and manual select the location of c:\Android_SDK\usb_driver.
  It should install the driver and show up as an ADB Device.
- Run adb kill-server then adb devices

**Remember to turn on USB debugging from the application settings as well**